# Can't figure out where "{}" come from when updating a Label widget with a string from a list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to update the text of a label in tkinter with values stored in a list when I noticed that tkinter seemingly adds '{}' to the label text when the passed list element is empty.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
list1 = [["someText"], []]
tk.Label(root, text=list1).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Can someone explain where the curly brackets come from and why they are added? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: That's just how tkinter converts `[]` to a string. I don't see why you need a nested list in the context, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `tkinter` library is an interface for `Tcl`/`Tk`. As part of this interfacing python has to decide how to interpret the values that you pass it. If you pass it a value where `str(value)` is falsey then it replaces it with `{}`, as shown in [this part of the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e5e1441d41907f92cc3bb5de675a2c519068173d/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L73).

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. It's true that tcl converts certain strings to `{}` but it's a bit more complicated than that. Tcl uses braces to preserves the structure of lists when they are converted to strings so it goes beyond just changing falsey values.

Comment: Ah thank you, I was under the impression that the conversion from a python `list` type to the python string `{}` was being done by the tkinter library that I linked to that wraps Tcl rather than by Tcl itself. Please feel free to edit my answer to improve its accuracy!